# bootstrap validation with identical values

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

We can make bootstrap validation for checking two field matches like bellow

```
data-match="#inputToMatch"
```

Is it possible to prevent entering identical values with this?something like  `data-not-match="#inputToMatch"` ?